# Mysql - Problem speed of access on query (Low latency query sometime)

Tags: mysql, php

My web application is real time site that need a **speed of access on every query** (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT) that **must less than 200ms**

Because one of my php script task is query (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT) the work on every secound
and then loop every secound alway across web server running.

Well, On average 98% each query time is less than 0.001-0.005 secound on each query stagement. **the problem is
Sometime around 3 time per hour, the query (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT) can take up to 1s and may be 5s,** so they has waiting and effect the next query loop that damage for whole business application.

i so find the solution such as row locking, turning mysql it not ensure speed of access less than 200ms, sometime it query 5s ooh!!
but the solution that i found to reducing the problem are move that from **INNODB to MEMORY** but sometime still a problem and the important thing are the need the recovery when system has crash.

> Example >> in some UPDATE problem that table size < 1M with 30 record and update on primary key it not sence

**the question are** it has many thing effect each other. HOW to slove this problem. How to start to find problem.

Do you have any idea or algorithm or **if u need more some information i will give you.**

thank you
so sorry about my english. i am thai

Answer (score -2):

You may switch the table from innodb to memory, but ensure the size of the table isn't that huge so that it doesn't eat up entire of its memory. Yes, you may safe guard or recover the table during system crash. Have master/slave replication setup and once the table is created on master with memory as engine type and change the table engine type to innodb (on slave only). So that even at the instance of master crash/restart you will get the data from slave.

Comment: Thank for answer, But How to know the number of io (read and write) that can effect each query and decrease performance or how number of read and write MEMORY table can effect performance

Comment: How big can your table grow? Calculate for the inserts only. How many inserts will it take in a day? And how big is your RAM?

Comment: OK thank, I use Amazon RDS Master don't convert MEMORY to INNODB on salve. How to set up?

Comment: Using `MEMORY` on master and `InnoDB` on slave is not sound advice for recovery purposes, because the first access of a memory table on the master, after restart, will trigger removal the contents of the table on the slave so that it's empty just like the one on the master... so this won't work. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-memory.html... and in RDS, you can't do this anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. Have you tried the method?

Comment: Update, still have problem. MEMORY ENGINE still slow in some time. Need help !!.

Comment: how big is your table?

Comment: some UPDATE problem that table size < 1M with 30 record and update on primary key

Comment: hold on!! 30 records and you say updates are slow? It shouldn't be even in innodb. By the way are you updating the primary key itself? If yes. Can you let me know the structure of the table. And update command that you issue.